# Use PHP printf to avoid duplicate variables in functions

Tags: javascript, php, printf, echo

I have some PHP Code like this:

```
echo sprintf('<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var UserId = "%s";
var UserNickname = "%s";
var UserEmailAddress = "%s";
var EmailVerified = "%s";
var Signature = "'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $userid . $user . $_SESSION['userinfo']['mail'] . "true", 'password', true)).'";
</script>', $userid, $user, $_SESSION['userinfo']['mail'], "true");
```

I was wondering if I could somehow use **sprintf** to get rid of the duplicate mentionings of my variables to simplify maintaining the code?

Comment: I'm not seeing any duplicate arguments there

Comment: All the variables used in this code are mentioned twice, but since they express the same thing it would make editing easier to unify them into one place

Comment: The variables you use for the hashing function cannot be reused in the `sprintf` method.